# AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'create_connection'

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, socks5

вот код:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://go.to',
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://490468888:Pitake3O@deimos.public.opennetwork.cc:1090',
                                 https='socks5://490468888:Pitake3O@deimos.public.opennetwork.cc:1090'))
```

вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/proxy-server.py", line 5, in <module>
    https='socks5://490468888:Pitake3O@deimos.public.opennetwork.cc:1090'))
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "D:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 79, in _new_conn
    conn = socks.create_connection(
AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код:

```
    import urllib3
    import telepot.api

    myproxy_url = 'http://140.227.69.74:8080/'
    telepot.api._pools = {'default': urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy_url=myproxy_url, num_pools=3, maxsize=10, retries=False, timeout=30),}
    telepot.api._onetime_pool_spec = (urllib3.ProxyManager, dict(proxy_url=myproxy_url, num_pools=1, maxsize=1, retries=False, timeout=30))
    bot = telepot.Bot('643365068:AAFUy0-mjRvYEPYuaivogRgW0TW_zzlCqus')

print(bot.getMe())
```